# Get data from API in app.module to pass as a module.forRoot() parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, mqtt

I am working with websockets and therefor using the MqttModule in Angular, which requires some service options in the forRoot parameter of the module import. Right now I have these settings hardcoded but would like to get them from the database, because that is where I've saved these settings. How can I achieve this? [image]

Comment: As per [this issue](https://github.com/sclausen/ngx-mqtt/issues/132) "You can set `connectOnCreate` to false in the options where you import the `MqttModule` and then later do a manual `connect` on the service with your retrieved options."

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the actual code and format it properly. Images are hard to read, impossible for people who use screen readers or to search.